# Purpose of hostNameType in Azure App Service hostname bindings

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to find out what the purpose of the `hostNameType` is in an Azure App Service resource definition. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/hostnamebindings) isn't very useful and indicates that the field only accepts two values: `Verified` and `Managed`. What do these two values mean ?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to how the hostname is registered:

- If you registered it in your own registrar (e.g. namecheap, godaddy, ...), it will be 'Verified'.
- If you buy it through the Azure Portal (Buy Domain under the Custom Hostname blade), it will be 'Managed'

Comment: Hey David, are the docs auto-generated or can I submit a PR with your improved descriptions on what each value means?

Comment: @Saca unfortunately, I don't think they are 'PR friendly' :(